# Ubuntu 17.10 | long time to reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, reboot

Got a fresh install of 17.10. All pass. On rebooting i got this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcG8z.jpg]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMTXX.jpg]

It take up to 20 min to done those jobs to stop.

Comment: What's PostFix busy doing?

Comment: There are a lot of errors being spewed out about the PCIe bus.  Try the fix here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected